# Creating an instance of a project class that we have no reference to using CreateInstance

Tags: c#, createinstance

I have 1 solution. With 3 project: Client, Visualisation and ClientInterface.

Project Client and Visualisation have reference to ClientInterface.

ClientInterface have class:

```
public abstract class VisualisationCollector
{        
    public abstract void Initialize();
}
```

Client:

```
public class Collector : VisualisationCollector
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
    protected override void Initialize(){...}
}
```

I am copy .dll from Client and past in Visualisation path:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Devices"
```

And now I am trying in Visualisation project:

```
var Collector = Activator.CreateInstance("Client", "Client.Collector").Unwrap();
```

I see only properties (but if there is a property of the class type, I can only see its name) from Collector without method. But I dont see method and properties from VisualisationCollector. And cant cast it on (VisualisationCollector) becouse throw:

> 'Unable to cast object of type' Client.Collector 'to type' ClientInterface.VisualisationCollector '.'

It work when I have reference in Visualisation  to Client. But i cant do that.

**Edit:**

Currently I have achieved what I wanted in this way. But I don't like downloading this assembly a second time (because before that I have already loaded this library with assembly). But I don't know how to get this type by name.

```
Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("Devices\\Client.dll"));
var form = assembly.CreateInstance("Client.Collector").GetType();
var assembly1 = Assembly.GetAssembly(form);
var vis = (VisualisationCollector)assembly1.CreateInstance("Client.Collector");
```

Comment: Do both Client and Visualization reference the same version of the ClientInterface assembly? You might also be interested in researching existing .NET plugin frameworks like MEF.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes these are the same version. I will check it.

Comment: You should avoid this if at all possible. If you need to construct objects defined in the client, the client should register a factory somehow in the clientInterface. So the Visualisation can use this factory to create objects. If you really need to you could iterate over all the types in the client assembly, find the types implementing some interface, and then create that type. This would make the code a bit less fragile.

Comment: @JonasH is correct. What's your reason for doing this? Are you trying to decouple your components or are you try to avoid circular dependencies or something else?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have a base application that loads device libraries (models) and creates a database dynamically, the application is universal and works for different sets of devices, and you only need to change the configuration file  and change library in file. I didnt make this app, I create a second app using what I already have. As far as I know, the person who did this was pretty good at programming. I don't know exactly why it works that way, but now I have to do it more like this.